# Can the rotation of an alpha particle be measured?

Tags: particle-physics

Although we can measure the energy of an alpha particle

[Measuring the energy of an alpha particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206150/measuring-the-energy-of-an-alpha-particle)

as well as the position and momentum, I cannot find papers that explore the motion of an alpha particle about its own axis.

Two ways that I thought of to investigate this might be:

1. the billiard ball analogy  -  if an alpha particle has a spin and it hits a nucleus, then it should preferentially scatter in one direction
2. Lorentz force change - if an alpha particle is not spinning and it travels through a magnetic field, it will deviate a specific amount for a specific magnetic field strength. If an alpha particle is spinning, its magnetic field (as a result of Faraday's law  that a spinning charge makes a magnetic field) will interact with the imposed magnetic field and cause a deviation from the expected path

Of course, generating a 'spinning' alpha particle is the trick. I could envision using conservation of angular momentum to do this. Get a bunch of alpha particles coming out of a cyclotron. Because these particles have been accelerated millions of times in a circle, they would have angular momentum. As they exit the cyclotron, they go straight so all that angular momentum goes from being a revolution in space to a rotation. Changing the polarity of the magnets in the cyclotron should give alpha particles spinning the opposite way. The paths of these two kinds of alpha particles should be different using a detector based one #1 or #2 above.

I am hoping a knowledgeable particle physicist may know of the experiments which explored this idea\ and give me a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot find papers that explore the motion of an alpha particle about its own axis.

That's because there isn't much to say about it. Alpha particles are quantum-mechanical objects and, as such, their rotational properties are governed by quantum mechanics. In QM, angular momentum is quantized, i.e. it can only take values from a discrete set of possibilities, which happens to be $\{0,\frac12,1,\frac32,2,\frac52,3,\ldots\}$, i.e. all integers and half-integers.

As it happens, alpha particles have angular momentum $J=0$. We know this from a huge base of evidence, both experimental (e.g. the lack of hyperfine structure in helium spectroscopy) and theoretical (where we have a solid understanding of nuclear structure). The implications of alpha particles having $J=0$ is that there is no sense in which they can be said to "rotate" internally. They hold no angular momentum beyond the 'orbital' angular momentum associated with the motion of their center of mass.

If you don't like this, tough. If you don't understand it, then you do need to start with an introductory quantum-physics textbook. The reason you can't find papers discussing the rotation of alpha particles it is that it's an easily solvable problem, at the level of an end-of-chapter exercise in an introductory nuclear physics textbook, or an obvious off-the-cuff remark (so see e.g. the start of §8.5 [here](https://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/PHYS/aanaqvi/Introductory-Nuclear-Physics-new-Krane.pdf)).

But, just to emphasize, if you try to probe it experimentally, you won't find anything.

> 1. the billiard ball analogy - if an alpha particle has a spin and it hits a nucleus, then it should preferentially scatter in one direction.

Alpha particles don't have spin, and they don't scatter preferentially in any direction that would be spin-dependent.

> 2. Lorentz force change - if an alpha particle is not spinning and it travels through a magnetic field, it will deviate a specific amount for a specific magnetic field strength. If an alpha particle is spinning, its magnetic field (as a result of Faraday's law that a spinning charge makes a magnetic field) will interact with the imposed magnetic field and cause a deviation from the expected path.

For particles with spin, the correct understanding is not the Lorentz force, but rather the force on a magnetic dipole in an inhomogeneous magnetic field, which is given by $\mathbf F = \nabla (\boldsymbol \mu\cdot\mathbf B)$, i.e. the gradient of the projection of the magnetic field onto the magnetic dipole moment $\boldsymbol \mu$. For quantum particles, the magnetic dipole moment is proportional to the spin, so this effect can be used to separate particles according to their angular momentum; this configuration is known as a [Stern-Gerlach device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment).

However, since alpha particles have no spin, they are not deflected by Stern-Gerlach devices.

---

That said, there's an additional misconception in your post, specifically when you say

> As they exit the cyclotron, they go straight so all that angular momentum goes from being a revolution in space to a rotation.

When they're circling around the cyclotron, the particles have orbital angular momentum $\mathbf L = \mathbf r\times\mathbf p$, which can be understood within classical mechanics, and which comes from the fact that the line of action of their velocity does not go through the origin (at the center of the cyclotron). If you release them so that they go straight out on a tangent to the circle, *that property is still true*, so they still have the same amount of (orbital) angular momentum.

Comment: There are excited nuclear states of He-4 I think that are bound.

Comment: @Pieter Yes, those states could indeed exist, though I get the sense that no bound excited states actually do (cf. e.g. table 3.0.1, p. 19, of [Nucl Phys A 541, 1 (1992)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0375-9474(92)90635-W)). In any case, assuming such bound states existed, I suspect it's unlikely that they'd be called 'alpha particles', with the notation $^4\mathrm{He}^*$ used instead (cf. the notation $\alpha + {}^4\mathrm{He}^*$, p. 17, *idem*).

Comment: @aquagremlin The paper linked in my previous comment is a good example of "papers that explore the motion of an alpha particle about its own axis", and what that looks like in the modern literature. (Basically, every time they quote a value of $J^\pi$, they're taking about the intrinsic rotational properties of the system.) If it's not readable to you, then it's unlikely that you should be looking for papers as such -- you should be reading textbooks in order to be able to understand the notation and the foundations.

Answer (score 1):

Alpha particles are scalar particles: they are perfectly spherical, and hence, don't spin.

The alpha is a 4 particle state, which I am not going to write out, but the general idea is that the wave function is a product of a spatial wave function and a spin wave function:

$$ \psi = \psi(\vec x) \times |j, j_z\rangle $$

For a spin-$0$ S-state:

$$ \psi = f(r)Y_{l=0}^{m=0}(\theta, \phi) \times |0, 0\rangle $$

where $f(r)$ is the radial wave function.

$\psi$ is perfectly spherical, and by that, I mean it is invariant under a rotation by an angle $\phi$ about a unit vector $\hat n$. That rotation operates on the spatial wave function via:

$$ \psi(\vec x) \rightarrow e^{-i\phi\frac{\hat n\cdot \vec L}{\hbar}}\psi(\vec x) =  \psi(\vec x)$$

where the last step uses $\vec L=0$.

Likewise, the spin part is mapped (using Wigner D-matrices to) $|0,0\rangle$.

What that means is that there is no way to even know if you have rotated the state. It is indistinguishable from the unrotated state.

This is analogous to translating a zero momentum plane-wave. A plane wave momentum eigenstate is:

$$ \psi(x) \propto e^{i(\vec p \cdot \vec x -E t)/\hbar}$$

which for $\vec p=0$ becomes:

$$ \psi(x) \propto 1 $$

which means that the state extends over all space with no phase variation. How do you translate it? It's just $1$ no matter what you do. Does it even mean anything to translate it? Likewise, rotating an alpha does nothing.

Comment: I am stupid. A ball is spherical and it can spin. Please explain.

Comment: Yup. Me too. Stupid. Please explain.

Comment: And how can an $\alpha$ be a $\text{He}_2^4$ and be "perfectly spherical"??

Comment: JEB has a ton of rep. I did not intend to be critical. And I did not down vote him.

Comment: @aquagremlin Without making any statement about **this** answer, the reputation of a user should not shield them from constructive criticism or requests for clarification, so don't be afraid to (politely) comment or downvote if warranted. Even the very highest reputation users occasionally write answers which are not so clear.

Comment: @Gert I mean scalars are invariant under rotations. Any rotation is equivalent to a non-rotation. Obviously, that is a quantum thing, but in our classical language, I take that to mean it is so perfectly spherical: you can't rotate it in any meaningful way. I would be interesting to write out a 4 particle wave function with spins and rotate it, because the component fermions rotate non-trivially, but they are in a superposition of states such that any rotation is equal to multiplication by $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. +1.

Comment: My question is not about theoretical explanation of spin or its meaning. I probably did not clearly state my question which is a search for the experiment that examined the behavior of alpha particles coming out of a cyclotron. I may just have to build my own cyclotron to do the experiment above, unless anyone knows where I can read if it's been done before.

Comment: @aquagremlin This might help: [Is there any hard scientific evidence that the alpha particle is tetrahedral?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309711/123208). Also see [How does an electron "move" in an s-orbital?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/115188/123208). Although that's about electrons, it applies fairly well to the protons & neutrons in an alpha particle, which are all in nuclear s-orbitals.

Comment: @Gert You may also find those links useful. I should mention that the nuclear shell model pretends that protons & neutrons are fundamental (i.e.,  not composite) particles. So the alpha isn't *perfectly* spherically symmetric, but it's very close.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes thank you for that link to Thomas' answer. It was interesting to see Emilio asking a similar question about other molecules like ammonia. Again the whole question is on of geometry of the nucleus and how that shapes the orbital. Though an alpha particle shouldn't have an orbital since there are no electrons there. But it still has an E field that is not spherical.

Comment: Also, user4552's comment  'All even-even nuclei have 0+ ground states, but not all of them are spherically symmetric. The ground state of an even-even nucleus is spherically symmetric in the lab frame. It has to be, because that's how angular momentum works in quantum mechanics. It's deformed in the body-fixed frame, which is what we describe, for example, in calculations using the deformed shell model. The single-particle wavefunctions, as well as any many-particle wavefunctions, constructed from such a model are not states of good angular momentum, which is a defect in the model. – user4552'

Answer (score 0):

There is confusion in your question. Particles of the size of alpha particles, i,e. helium nuclei, are **quantum mechanical entities** and the modeling of their interactions depend on quantum mechanics , its e[quations and postulates.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html)

In your question you are discussing the alpha particle as if it is a billiard ball. It is not. The term *spin* is taken from classical mechanics, but is defined differently: it is the value needed to be assigned to particles  in particle interactions so that the **law of angular momentum conservation** holds absolutely at the level of particle physics .

The spin of particles is inferred from their interactions with other particles in specific experiments. The [spin of the Higgs](https://atlas.cern/updates/physics-briefing/scalar-boson) is found by the angular dependence of the Higgs production crossection, for example.

Try reading the [wiki article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics))

Edit:

As you are thinking of the alpha particles classically like billiard balls and try to impose angular momentum conservation to the alpha ejected from  the cyclotron , you are ignoring that *the system is not closed* when the alpha leave the cyclotron, and that all three conservation laws hold for closed [**isolated systems**.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/conser.html)

Take a simple classical example: Think of a string with a ball at the end and a man turning it around in the air. String breaks. What happens? Ball goes off straight on a tangent. What happens with the angular momentum it had? the man rotates the other way and balances it. The closed system was "man +string+ball".

In the cyclotron when the alpha particles leave, the system is open. The isolated system "cyclotron with alpha" will balance the angular momentum with the magnetic fields that were constraining the alpha tracks , the way the man+string constrains the ball track.

So even with classical physics the ball does not take rotation about itself when the forces acting upon it are removed. For a "spin rotation" to appear on an object, there should be a force applied whose vector direction does not point to the center of mass of the object.

For quantum mechanical objects,(as the [alpha particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_particle) ), spins, i.e. rotations about self, are intrinsic and part of **the definition** of the particle.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my comment as an answer because it wont fit in a comment block. I marked Emilio's response as the answer because he was the only one who mentioned that data is available (the lack of hyperfine structure in helium spectroscopy). I will have to search more in that direction. Regarding the NUMEROUS answers that tell me that an alpha particle is a point charge, I appreciate not only your guidance but also the time you took to write down the QM model. However, I should explain my motivation for my question as it really boils down to the fact that the E field of alpha particle is not a spherically symmetric thing but more of an ellipsoid. How else could you arrange two protons except for being side by side. I am ignoring the neutrons as they do no contribute to the E field.

As these ellipsoid charges enter the cyclotron, the population is spinning in every which way. And since it is a positive charge, it will have a magnetic field. (Would I say magnetic moment? I am not sure of the correct term. I cannot imagine how schools expect students to learn online. Without being around other people, without being in a lab, without being able to talk in between classes the experience is bad. We are reducing school to an ersatz activity but that is another rant.)

Anyway this little football (american football not European, or should I say rugby ball?) will reach the end of a dee and start to experience the opposite electric field and it will start to accelerate. Since only one pointy end of the football will peek out into the external E field, that will start to get accelerated first. The football will start to tumble the same way that an off center kick will cause a real football to tumble. Or the same way that a discus thrower launches a discus with a spin. Imagine for clarity that the induced tumbling is in the plane of the cyclotron.

But once the whole football is in the homogeneous E field, the whole thing gets accelerated equally. Now its tumbling towards the other dee, gaining speed, faster and faster in a linear direction. but its still tumbling though the tumbling is not being accelerated. The tumbling of the football generates a magnetic field. If this field happens to be coincident with the externally applied magnetic field, it's fine. If however, the football is tumbling the other way, its magnetic field will be opposite to the externally applied field. And like what happens when two north poles are brought together, the football is repelled. The particle leaves the spiral orbit and crashes into the cyclotron.

Of course, there are details like what happens if the football happens to be tumbling in some other random direction, not in the plane of the cyclotron. Then I would say that its tumbling is a combination of velocities: the horizontal tumbling I talked about above and a vertical tumbling component. The horizontal tumbling component will force the particle out of the cyclotron plane in some cases as I described above. The vertical tumbling component will be in either of two directions (forward or backward?) This will generate a force towards or away from the the center of the cyclotron.

But ultimately, all footballs not spinning the proper way will get kicked out of the spiral and not make the whole journey.

That's why I wanted to see the data that said there is no spinning/tumbling/rotation of this little football of protons. Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: (I moved my comments here, so as to not clutter JEB's answer). Nuclear orbitals are quite similar to electron orbitals, because both kinds of orbitals arise due to Pauli exclusion. But there are important differences, too. Electrons are fundamental particles, and electron orbitals are structured around a positive nucleus. OTOH, nucleons are composite particles, there are 2 kinds of nucleon, and the nuclear shell structure doesn't have an "inner nucleus". The 4 nucleons of an alpha particle are in 1S nuclear orbitals, that have spherical symmetry, just like the 1s electron orbitals do.

Comment: Sure, the nuclear shell model isn't perfect, partly because it ignores the quark structure of nucleons, as I mentioned earlier. Also, it's more complicated than electron shell theory, because there's 2 kinds of nucleon, and 2 forces: the (residual) strong force, which acts on all nucleons, plus the electrostatic repulsion between protons. But for simple nuclei containing only a small number of nucleons, it's a very accurate & useful model, unless you want to know how they behave at *very* high energies.

Comment: Nobody (on this page) claimed that an alpha particle is a point charge. But we are claiming that it's spherical. *"How else could you arrange two protons except for being side by side."* Your classical intuition of geometry is leading you astray. The 2 protons are in the same 1S position state, with opposite spins, conventionally referred to as spin up and spin down. Similarly, the 2 electrons in a neutral helium atom in the ground state are in the 1s state, one spin up, the other spin down.

Comment: I don't dispute that I should think of an alpha particle then as a wavefunction with charge +2, mass +4, and spin 0. But I still would like to see the experimental results from experiments that prove this. The mass part and charge part are easy. It's the spin part I couldn't find info on.

Comment: "the E field of alpha particle is not a spherically symmetric thing but more of an ellipsoid" -- to be clear, this is categorically incorrect. "How else could you arrange two protons except for being side by side?" -- in a quantum mechanical way, in which neither proton has a well-defined position, nor do they have a well-defined relative position.